# Azure OpenAI access issue with Azure for Students subscription

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, openai-api

I have ran to an issue when trying to access Azure OpenAI with my Azure for Students subscription ID. The thing is that I applied for OpenAI through filling up the entry request form, entering student subscription ID there (suppose this was the primary mistake). Next day I got an e mail from Cognitive services, that my request was successful and I'm approved to use OpenAI services.
The problem is following: When I put there my Azure for Students subscription ID, which is managed through university, I can't even create a new resource group as I don't have the permission to do so. When I try to create resource with my second account, It obviously doesn't work as this account subscription ID isn't the one whitelisted for using OpenAI services. I would be super-glad for any kind of help or ideas, how to make this work in my situation. Thanks in advance and have a nice day!
Cheers,
T.

I've already tried to ask my university admin, but they didn't help me. I went through the documentation and FAQs of Azure, and I asked on Microsoft's Azure support on Twitter.